# I need to use a Windows program, and have low RAM, how can I use Ubuntu as an alternative of Windows XP?

Tags: 20.10, windows-xp

I have a software that only runs on windows XP, but whenever I try to start my laptop and open boot settings, choose optical drive, and select it, the screen freezes for some time, and then boots into Ubuntu 20.10. I don’t see what I did wrong here.. Any help is appreciated :)
Also, if you need: my laptop is a very old HP compaq which is almost 10+ years old. Do I need some kind of driver to read my disc or am I doing some step wrong?

Is there any way to use the software in Ubuntu without replacing Ubuntu with Windows XP?

EDIT: So I also have another problem, I have very less ram, about 2 Gb as my laptop is very old, so I will probably want to use full 2 Gb ram for windows so instead of using virtual box as it freezes my computer.

Comment: How-do-I-get-the-Windows-installer-to-work does not seem like an Ubuntu-related question. It seems like a Windows support question. Advice: Installing a dead OS that has multiple exploits in the wild seems foolish. Don't do it. Find another way.

Comment: FYI:  I'm running Lubuntu *impish* (what will be 21.10 on release) on a 2009 dell desktop (c2q-q9400) and it runs well; thankfully I have more RAM (I have a more modern thinkpad with i5-m520 which is much more of a pain to use having less ram).  I opt for *lighter* flavors of Ubuntu on my older hardware (I have Ubuntu installed on this my 2009 dell, but it's not as nice an experience, even on newer hardware with less ram).  I use 2GB laptops in QA-testing Lubuntu & some flavors, eg. `lenovo thinkpad sl510 (c2d-t6570, 2gb ram, i915)`

Comment: As for running a windows program under a *ubuntu system, it'll depend on the software in question which you didn't name.  Your question however reads like you want to replace an on-topic OS (Ubuntu) with an off-topic OS thus making your question off-topic here. Booting a OS from media is specific to your hardware (ie. a hardware/firmware question & off-topic here too though we may help if you're trying to install an on-topic system).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't install Windows XP in your computer. Its extended support was discontinued in 2014. It would be very much prone to malware as soon as you connect to internet. AFAIK, major browsers have stopped supporting it too.

Either use a [Virtual Machine](https://itsfoss.com/install-virtualbox-ubuntu/) to run Windows XP inside Ubuntu, or use [Wine](http://winehq.org) to emulate the software.

Also, many popular Windows software have equivalent free and open source software in Ubuntu, so we may be able to recommend you an equivalent software if you tell what you need.

### Less RAM issue

2 GB RAM is not enough for Ubuntu 20.10.
I suggest you to use Xubuntu or Lubuntu 20.04 instead (or Kubuntu, without any fancy effects. The RAM usage of Kubuntu is very similar to Xubuntu). They need relatively less resource to run. Also, the 20.04 version is a long term support release, so you can stick to the same operating system for a long time.

In case even [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) or [Lubuntu](https://lubuntu.me/) seem to be slow, you can use other distros tailored for older computers. Some examples of such distros are [LXLE](https://lxle.net/), [Puppy Linux](https://puppylinux.com/), [anTiX](https://antixlinux.com/) or [Bodhi](https://www.bodhilinux.com).

Note that they are not supported on this website. But being Debian based, the user experience would be very similar to Ubuntu.

Alternatively, if you don't need to regularly connect the computer to internet, you can use an older version of Ubuntu (e.g. Xubuntu 14.04). That would be still a lot safer than Windows XP (even such an older version of Ubuntu won't be affected by a USB drive affected with virus).

With such a lighter OS, you would have enough free RAM to run a virtual machine (even 200 MB RAM is enough for XP), or emulate the software in Wine.

Comment: Here is my problem, I have very less ram, about 2gb as it is a very old laptop, running virtual box literally freezes my computer, hence I did not go that way, other wise I would have used virtual box as I have experience in it already

Comment: @CodeMaster Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1336553/edit) to update the question. I would update my answer to.

Comment: @Archisman, do you think if OP installed a “lighter” version of Ubuntu (like Xububtu or Lububtu) he could run the legacy Windows program in Wine. If the program is old enough, Wine will probably have comparability with it. What do you think?

Comment: @PJSingh Yes, that may be true.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I was able to find a somewhat compatible software in Ubuntu, hence I've decided not to install XP, also yes, I would have connected to the internet making my system vurnerable, thanks for making me aware :d